# LINQ query to find average cost per item by region

Tags: linq

I have a winforms app and a database consisting of shop data and item sales data. In the data retrieved from the database I would like to filter the resultant object collection using LINQ. What LINQ query do I need to join the `Shop` and `ItemSale` objects and query them to select group by Region and the average cost for each item?

```
Shop.cs
StoreId
Name
Region

ItemSale.cs
Name
Cost
Region
```

**Required output:**

```
Region Name | Average Item cost
Region1     | 22.50
Region2     | 15.30
Region3     | 15.90
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to use linq expression queries when working with joins.

```
var querySelect =
    from r in Shop
    join i in ItemSale on r.Region equals i.Region
    select new
    {
        Region = r.Region,
        ItemCost = r.Cost
    };
```

I find it easier to use lambda linq queries for groups

```
var queryGroup = querySelect
    .GroupBy(m => new { m.Region }
    .Select(m => new
    {
        Region = m.Key.Region,
        AverageItemCost = m.Average(x => x.ItemCost)
    };
```

You could do both of these queries in one, but I figured it would be easier to understand as two separate queries and there is no significant performance gain from combining them.

Comment: The queries are generated in the application layer.  Once you call `.ToList()` on the query it is executed on your SQL Server.  As a result the application has no real performance gains from doing all this in one query vs two as once it hits your SQL Server it is just one query.